# Как убрать пустые значение из массива при file_get_contents

Tags: веб-программирование, массивы

Содержимое

в общем между значениями переход на новую строку и пробел
тут этого не видно..

```
version = ‘1.3.15’                
source.id = ‘1’     
source.path = ‘some/path’
login.remember = ‘1’
login.name = ‘userName’
login.password = ‘password’
awful.layout = ‘split’
awful.layout.suit = ‘tile’
```

Код:

```
$lines = file_get_contents('file.txt',  FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
//разбиваем файловую строку по строкам
echo $lines;
$resLines = explode("\n",$lines);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($resLines);
echo '</pre>';
```

Результат:

```
Array (
    [0] => version = ‘1.3.15’
    [1] => 
    [2] =>  
    [3] => 
    [4] => source.id = ‘1’
    [5] => 
    [6] =>  
    [7] => 
    [8] => source.path = ‘some/path’
    [9] => 
    [10] =>  
    [11] => 
    [12] => login.remember = ‘1’
    [13] => 
    [14] =>  
    [15] => 
    [16] => login.name = ‘userName’
    [17] => 
    [18] =>  
    [19] => 
    [20] => login.password = ‘password’
    [21] => 
    [22] =>  
    [23] => 
    [24] => awful.layout = ‘split’
    [25] => 
    [26] =>  
    [27] => 
    [28] => awful.layout.suit = ‘tile’ )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Способы разные есть. Один из простейших:

```
$clean_array = array_diff($resLines,array(''));
// или 
$clean_array = array_filter($resLines);
```

**UPD**
Пример, где учитывается  и пробелы:

```
function unset_empty_values(array $array) {
    function filter_unset($value) {
        return !empty($value) || $value == ' ' ? $value : false;
    }
    return array_filter($array, "filter_unset");
}

$result = unset_empty_values($resLines);
```

Если надо учитывать какие-то еще символы (видимые или нет), то добавьте в условие

Comment: @Deonis не рабочий
там присутствует например в 26 пробел в 27 25 полное заполнение строки- в файле переход строки

Comment: Читайте **UPD** в ответе